# how to `go install` from gitea

Tags: go, gitea, goinstall

I'm trying to install a package from a self-hosted gitea instance. I'm trying to get a package running `go install gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir` but I'm getting this error

```bash
no required module provides package gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir; to add it:
        go get gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir
```

Any help would be appreciated to show me how can I configure my go env.

I've set `GOPRIVATE="gitea.urkob.com/urko"` but it still not working, I don't know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`go install` is used to install a binary, not a package.

Whereas in your case, gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir is only a package, because when I tried with `go get`, I'm getting:

```bash
$ go get -v gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir
get "gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir.git"} at //gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir?go-get=1
gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir (download)
gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir
# gitea.urkob.com/urko/go-root-dir
runtime.main_mainÂ·f: function main is undeclared in the main package
```

If you meant it to be a binary, then put/specify a `main` function for it.

Comment: oh thanks, let my try. I'll give you answer soon.

Comment: It worked! I've got confused by two options. I would swear I saw that `go get` will be deprecated and that's why I used instead go install ... anyway thanks so much